# Add categories to custom post type and display based on categories

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I am working on a wordpress site with theme name **flozo** . It has a custom post type named `work`.
I wanted to display the works in my template based on each category.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => 15 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = 0;
echo '<ul>';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $count++;
    $class = ($count % 3 == 1) ? 'first' : '';

    echo '<li class="'.$class.'">';
    echo '<a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    echo '<div class="overlay" style="background-color:'.ot_get_option( 'main_colour' ).';"></div>';
    the_post_thumbnail('full');
    echo '</a>';

    echo '<br />';

    echo '<h2><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a></h2>';

    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '30'); 
    echo '..</div>';
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I've added

```
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'work', 'tag_ID' => 15 ,'posts_per_page' => 15 );
```

where `15` is the id of my category, but it didn't work

I've also tried

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=15&posts_per_page=3' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul class="last-cat">
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> <p><?php     the_title(); ?></p><span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span></a></li></ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

which also didn't help.

**Edit:**

The category url is

> http://jointviews.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=categories&tag_ID=15&post_type=work

The post type registration code is :

```
add_action('init', 'work_register');   

function work_register() {   

$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x('Work', 'post type general name'), 
    'singular_name' => _x('Work Item', 'post type singular name'), 
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'work item'), 
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Work Item'), 
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Work Item'), 
    'new_item' => __('New Work Item'), 

    'view_item' => __('View Work Item'), 
    'search_items' => __('Search Work'), 
    'not_found' => __('Nothing found'), 
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '' 
);   

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels, 
    'public' => true, 
    'publicly_queryable' => true, 
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'query_var' => true, 
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png', 
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'work', 'with_front'=> false ), 'capability_type' => 'post', 
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'menu_position' => null, 
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail') 
);   

register_post_type( 'work' , $args ); 

register_taxonomy("categories", array("work"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Category", "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'work', 'with_front'=> false )));



}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `tag_ID` needs to be `tag_id`.

Comment: http://jointviews.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=categories&tag_ID=15&post_type=work    this the url look like for my category

Comment: to read the values that has passed through url .. not for accesing it

Comment: how can i display it then? it isto display my works

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both of the other answers are incorrect, specially the one from the OP. `query_posts` should **NEVER EVER** be used, it is even stated in the codex, so please, read the codex. Also, you should never replace the main query with custom queries.

The solution is simple as I have described below and **it is the correct way** of doing it.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

You have a couple of flaws here

- For your custom post type to have an archive, you need to set the `has_archive` parameter to `true` in your custom post type registration arguments. See [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
- If you are not going to use your custom post type like pages, set the `hierarchical` parameter to `false`. Setting this to true will considerably slow down your backend as your posts increase as Wordpress will try to build a tree for each post like it does for pages
- Never use custom queries in place of the main query. It is always more troublesome and a waste of resources. See [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) for a full explanation on where and when to use custom queries correctly.
- This point is an extension of the previous one. If you need to change the main query, use `pre_get_posts` to do so. It uses the same exact parameters as `WP_Query` as the main query uses `WP_Query` to fetch posts. This is all explained in the linked post above
- Your main flaw in your custom query is your lack of understanding what the difference is between categories, tags and custom taxonomies. I have written a complete post ( which you can read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) ) on this and actually entered it into the codex as well. You are making use of a custom taxonomy, so the category parameters won't work. You need to use a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for custom taxonomies

To solve your issue, follow the following steps

- Add the `has_achive` parameter to your arguments when registering your custom post type and set it to `true`. If you want, set the `hierarchical` parameter to `false` as well in your custom post type. (*Do not set this for your custom taxonomy, this will make your taxonomy behave like normal tags*)
- After this, flush your rewrite rules by visiting the permalink page under "Settings" and clicking "Update"
- Visit your homepage just to make sure your new rules is saved
- Delete your custom query and go back to the default loop. Your `archive-work.php` should look like this

  ```
  if( have_posts() ) {
      while( have_posts() ) {
          the_post();

          // Your custom markup and template tags

      }
  }
  ```
- If you need to display posts from a specific term, create a `taxonomy.php`, `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}.php` or `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term}.php` template. Check the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) for more info

### EDIT 1

If you only need to show a specific term on your custom post type archive term, after you have done the above, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query the correct way

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'work' ) ) {
        $q->set( 'categories', 'slides' );
    }

});
```

### EDIT 2

Here is code to solve this

Copy and paste the following code in place of your code where you register your post type. I have added the `has_archive` parameter. I have also changed the rewrite rule for your taxonomy to `categories`. It is really troublesome to have the same slug for both custom post type and taxonomy. This does not work by default and completely throws everything off target

```
add_action( 'init', 'work_register' );   

function work_register() {   

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x('Work', 'post type general name'), 
        'singular_name' => _x('Work Item', 'post type singular name'), 
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'work item'), 
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Work Item'), 
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Work Item'), 
        'new_item' => __('New Work Item'), 

        'view_item' => __('View Work Item'), 
        'search_items' => __('Search Work'), 
        'not_found' => __('Nothing found'), 
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => '' 
    );   

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels, 
        'public' => true, 
        'publicly_queryable' => true, 
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true, 
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png', 
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'work', 'with_front'=> false ), 
        'capability_type' => 'post', 
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,  
        'menu_position' => null, 
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail') 
    );   

    register_post_type( 'work' , $args ); 

    register_taxonomy( 'categories', array('work'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'label' => 'Categories', 
        'singular_label' => 'Category', 
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'categories', 'with_front'=> false )
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'categories', 'work' ); // Better be safe than sorry
}
```

In your archive-work.php, replace your custom query with this code

```
<?php

$count = 0;
echo '<ul>';
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $count++;
    $class = ($count % 3 == 1) ? 'first' : '';

    echo '<li class="'.$class.'">';
    echo '<a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    echo '<div class="overlay" style="background-color:'.ot_get_option( 'main_colour' ).';"></div>';
    the_post_thumbnail('full');
    echo '</a>';

    echo '<br />';

    echo '<h2><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a></h2>';

    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '30'); 
    echo '..</div>';
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

**VERY IMPORTANT** -> OK, now visit *Settings >> Permalinks* in the back end (admin area) and click *Save Changes*. This will flush your permalinks and set your new permalink structure

You should now see all your post from your custom post type when you visit

> http://example.com/work/

Comment: hi i am bit busy with someother work .. i will get back to this soon :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'work', 'categories' => 'slides' ) );
//the loop start here
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

i finally got it from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/displaying-custom-posts-by-category) 
perfect

Comment: `query_posts` is one of the worst functions to use. If I can give you one tip, **never ever** use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query, rerun SQL queries, slowing your page down (which is bad for SEO), breaks and stuffs up pagination, breaks the `$wp_query` and `$post` globals as well as `get_queried_object()` which is widely used by plugins. It might solve your issue now, but you will get lot of crap later on

Comment: BTW, that linked answer is totally wrong, old and incorrect, downvoted as such.

Comment: i am bit bad in coding . so i would like to get some code to solve the issue .. not an expert to write my own yet

Comment: OK, I will try to help you. See my answer in 5 min

Comment: OK, check my update. First do what I have said in my **EDIT 2**. Get this to work, then reply back if you need anything more

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code,

```
<?php 

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5,'post_type' => 'work','category' => 15 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ):?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in /home/jvadmin/public_html/wp-content/themes/flozo/archive-work.php on line 17

Comment: @Melvin Are the posts in the category with the id (15)?

Comment: i changed 'category' => 15 to 'tag_ID' => 15 .. but now all th eposts are displaying http://jointviews.com/portfolio/  you can see near the footer

Comment: So you got the custom posts(work) under the category?

Comment: it came with the theme